# pencil-sharpening (procrastination) link wanted

Tags: reference

In spite of using the advanced search options of Google search, I cannot pin down a single instance of the ironic meaning of “pencil-sharpening” of “unnecessary preparation as a pretext for delaying getting down to work”. So, if someone could come up with such a reference, I would certainly appreciate it.

I saw the term used in this sense in some printed remarks by a novelist (female, and British, as I recall), the relevant novel, which I read, being, I think from the 1930’s.

Following up on ab2’s suggestion that it might be Dorothy Sayers, I googled for “Dorothy Sayers” together with “pencil sharpening” and found a website with a use of the term in the sense that I am seeking:

“Forget all the writerly delays, the websites to check out, the email to answer - how modern technology has expanded the pencil sharpening and paper straightening of yesteryear. But if I want the end of the story, I have to get to work.”

http://www.sleuthsayers.org/search/label/Janice%20Law?updated-max=2012-01-04T21:01:00-08:00&max-results=20&start=16&by-date=false

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing the term used in that sense, except perhaps as a part of a larger phrase incorporating several such office preparation steps.

Comment: How about [Yukon News](http://yukon-news.com/letters-opinions/pencil-sharpening-warranted)?

Comment: (Something along the lines of "sharpening pencils and straightening papers".)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - It's not totally clear, but that use of "pencil sharpening" appears to refer to using sharp pencils to do accurate financial calculations, another use of the term and one that is totally opposite of the OP's sense.

Comment: There is "***sharpen your pencil"*** but the meaning is different: http://www.effective-business-letters.com/Sharpen-Your-Pencil.html

Comment: (A point is being made here that "sharpening pencils", used without other context, is more likely to be taken to mean doing careful planning and calculation than to mean procrastinating.)

Comment: It appears there's an entire book on the subject...an extended irony if you will: see ["Pencils and Nothingness"](http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/pencils-and-nothingness) and ["Psychological Risks Associated With Pencil Sharpening...](http://www.theawl.com/2012/04/psychological-risks-associated-with-pencil-sharpening-from-david-rees-how-to-sharpen-pencils). There are a lot more where that came from, but I have to get a drink of water.

Comment: Who was the novelist?  It sounds like Dorothy Sayers.

Comment: @ab2: My guess is that it was indeed Dorothy Sayers. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you're still looking -- try googling pencil sharpening writer's block.  Lots of good stuff there.

Answer (score 2):

See [Structured Procrastination](http://www.structuredprocrastination.com/)

> The key idea is that procrastinating does not mean doing absolutely
>   nothing. Procrastinators seldom do absolutely nothing; they do
>   marginally useful things, like gardening or sharpening pencils or
>   making a diagram of how they will reorganize their files when they get
>   around to it.

See also 
[Sharpening Pencils Isn’t Writing – 4 Signs You’re Procrastinating](http://www.aboutfreelancewriting.com/2011/09/29/sharpening-pencils-isnt-writing-4-signs-youre-procrastinating/) by Anne Wayman   on September 29, 2011

And, finally, from the LA Times [When Getting Ready to Write, Sharpen Your Pencil](http://articles.latimes.com/2006/dec/10/magazine/tm-rules50)

All I did was Google:  sharpening pencil, procrastination

Answer (score 1):

No discussion of pencil sharpening would be complete without reference to this site: http://www.artisanalpencilsharpening.com where David Rees will send you a hand-sharpened pencil for just $40, with a 6- to 8-week shipping time. To pass the time while waiting for your artisanally sharpened pencil to arrive, you can order and read his groundbreaking book, *How to Sharpen a Pencil,"* available on Amazon or at your local independent bookstore. See: [http://www.amazon.com/How-Sharpen-Pencils-Theoretical-Contractors/dp/1612193269](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1612193269)

Comment: I like that you get the shavings from the sharpened pencil.  This will be really useful when the power goes down and you need kindling for your wood stove.